# Use onchange in a div

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

Is it possible to use `onchange` event in a `<div>`?

Because my `<div>` changes its text inside.

Can I do something like this?

```
<div id="name" onchange="calculateTotal();"></div>
```

Comment: Does the user change the text or do you do it programmatically?

Comment: then it doesn't change, it is initialized

Comment: @Rafael Santos: When PHP updates it, do you do it through AJAX or through a new page request?

Comment: It can't be changed with PHP, it is either changed by Javascript (PHP -> Ajax -> Javascript) or pregenerated by PHP.

Comment: [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) says: *The onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This attribute applies to the following elements: INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.* So no, it is not possible like this. Suggestion: When you change the content, compare the new value against the old one and perform the action.

Comment: Thanks everybody, but how can I do that?

Comment: @Rafael Santos: Well, in case you do it with Ajax - you should trigger your change event manually in Ajax callback function. What framework do you use for AJAX? And could you paste your AJAX code and update your question with new info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say you're using AJAX, why not execute the function when you update the text. I'm not sure if you use any library, but in case it's jQuery just do:

```
 $.ajax({ ...,
          success: function() {
               ... other things ...
               ... setting div text ...
               calculateTotal();
          }
       });
```

Comment: I am using CakePHP, and jquery.

Comment: @Rafael Santos: Then this should do the job. Whatever happens on the PHP side, PHP just delivers the appropriate data which is out of scope for your problem.

Answer (score 26):

No; the `onchange` attribute is only applicable to form field elements (`input`, `select`, `textarea`, *etc*).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.How do I do it?

Comment: Link to documentation related to this?

Comment: By now the keygen HTML-Element is supported as well. Here is the link to the documentation: Have a look under "Technical Details" 
Have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp

Answer (score 4):

As you are changing the text yourself, just call `calculateTotal` when the AJAX call completes and the text has been placed in the element.

Example (using jQuery):

```
$('#name').load('GetFragment.php', calculateTotal);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit over most webdesigners paygrade, but it's not any problem to monitor a div using the dom.
It's also pure vanilla javascript, so nothing required.

The most easy way to show it is with a example. The Div is editable so just click on it and type something and your javascript console will show what is going on. (if you don't know your way around the javascript debugger this might be to hard for you, so just learn it ;) )

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
        // Run the code once the DOM is created, think jquery $(function(){}); but HTML5
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            const commandlineDiv = document.getElementById('commandline');
            function mutationCallback(mutationsList, observer) {
                console.log(mutationsList);
                console.log(observer);
                for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
                    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                        console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
                    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
                        console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
                    } else {
                        console.log('mutation.type: ' + mutation.type);
                        console.log('New value ' + JSON.stringify(mutation.target.data));
                    }
                }
            }
            // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
            const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
            // What to observe
            const mutationConfig = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true };
            observer.observe(commandlineDiv, mutationConfig);
        })

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="commandline" contentEditable="true">commandline</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great example. The OP doesn't actually need this for his problem, but this is an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'onInput' instead of 'onChange'.

```
<div className="inputDiv" contenteditable="true" onInput={(e) => { console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent) }} />
```

Check the console log with Chrome Developer Tools (F12):

[image]

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614631/8706661

Comment: This is for reactjs. Not for html and js

Comment: thanks KOMODO, that is a very important note, `onInput={` was a give away for me.

Comment: The goal of the question (although it isn't clear and you have to pay attention to the comments on the question and **the accepted answer from 2011**) is to detect when **JavaScript** modifies the text content of the div. Your code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Onchange is called when user changed input value. So answer is yes, but it will have no effect.
I assume you change content programmatically, so add simple code which will call this function

Comment: what's the input value of a div?

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, `calculateTotal` will not fire when div text content change. However, if that div contains an input as child, then `calculateTotal` would fire if user changed that child input, like checking a checkbox. It's just because of the change event of input could be propagating up the DOM tree, a feature of events called Event Propagation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use onblur event. Onblur event working on table,div etc.

```
<div id="name" onblur="calculateTotal();"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your div to a textarea or button or input
You can't use onchange in div

Comment: The goal of the question (although it isn't clear and you have to pay attention to the comments on the question and **the accepted answer from 2011**) is to detect when JavaScript modifies the text content of the div. Changing the element to a textarea or input would allow user input to be detected with a change event, but that's not the goal here. Change events do not fire on buttons.