# React.js: onChange event for contentEditable

Tags: javascript, dom, contenteditable, reactjs

How do I listen to change events for a `contentEditable`-based control?

```
var Number = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <span contentEditable={true} onChange={this.onChange}>
                {this.state.value}
            </span>
            =
            {this.state.value}
        </div>;
    },
    onChange: function(v) {
        // Doesn't fire :(
        console.log('changed', v);
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {value: '123'}
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Number />, document.body);
```

[Code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NV/kb3gN/1621/).

Comment: Having struggled with this myself, and having issues with suggested answers, I decided to make it uncontrolled instead. That is, I put `initialValue` into `state` and use it in `render`, but I don't let React update it further.

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't work

Comment: I avoided struggling with ```contentEditable``` by changing my approach - instead of a ```span``` or ```paragraph```, I've used an ```input``` along with its ```readonly``` attribute.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

See [Sebastien Lorber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677931/react-js-onchange-event-for-contenteditable/27255103#27255103) which fixes a bug in my implementation.

---

Use the onInput event, and optionally onBlur as a fallback.  You might want to save the previous contents to prevent sending extra events.

I'd personally have this as my render function.

```
var handleChange = function(event){
    this.setState({html: event.target.value});
}.bind(this);

return (<ContentEditable html={this.state.html} onChange={handleChange} />);
```

### [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vamuxayu/2/edit?js,output)

Which uses this simple wrapper around contentEditable.

```
var ContentEditable = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div
            onInput={this.emitChange}
            onBlur={this.emitChange}
            contentEditable
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.html}}></div>;
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps){
        return nextProps.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
    },
    emitChange: function(){
        var html = this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
        if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {

            this.props.onChange({
                target: {
                    value: html
                }
            });
        }
        this.lastHtml = html;
    }
});
```

Comment: @NVI, it's the shouldComponentUpdate method.  It'll only jump if the html prop is out of sync with the actual html in the element.  e.g. if you did `this.setState({html: "something not in the editable div"}})`

Comment: nice but I guess the call to `this.getDOMNode().innerHTML` in `shouldComponentUpdate` is not very optimized right

Comment: @SebastienLorber not *very* optimized, but I'm pretty sure it's better to read the html, than to set it.  The only other option I can think of is to listen to all events that could change the html, and when those happen you cache the html.  That'd probably be faster most of the time, but add a lot of complexity.  This is the very sure and simple solution.

Comment: This is actually slightly flawed when you want to set `state.html` to the last "known" value, React will not update the DOM because the new html is exactly the same as far as React is concerned (even though the actual DOM is different). See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSP3s/1/). I have not found a good solution for this, so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: @univerio what about setting DOM's `innerHTML` right inside `shouldComponentUpdate`? See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSP3s/3/).

Comment: @dchest `shouldComponentUpdate` should be pure (not have side effects).

Comment: Using `this.lastHtml` is bad because you assign a variable to the component class and not to its instance state

Comment: @SebastienLorber I believe [this demo](http://jsbin.com/muduwemo/2/edit?js,output) disproves that.  Let me know if I'm missing something.  If `this.x` was shared, they'd display the same number after "id:".

Comment: I find your exemple quite complex but it seems you are right: http://jsfiddle.net/4TpnG/300/ however I didn't see anywhere in the doc that it was recommended to add things in `this` instead of the state

Comment: @SebastienLorber right on the front page of the react docs they show this pattern. The "stateful component" example stores the timer's id on the instance directly: `this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);`

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I've posted a new answer which fixes a little bug in your implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677931/react-js-onchange-event-for-contenteditable/27255103#27255103

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I am back with another question but could you explain why you choose to handle the onBlur event to emit a change?

Comment: IE9 has some bugs with the input event (backspace doesn't trigger it), and I think there was some other case where it isn't called.. the onBlur is intended as a fallback, even if it's a delayed one.

Comment: I downvoted this and upvoted Sebastien's answer so that it rises to the top. I hope that is the correct process to follow.

Comment: Wasn't documentation absolutely explicit on __never ever using__ `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: ...}}`? Cannot user just copy-paste some `<script>` or `<img onerror="some.evil.magic()">` from third-party website? I see no single word on filtering such things [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/).

Comment: Nice, but won't work in IE11. onInput event for contentEditable div is not working there: https://jsfiddle.net/dbmu8yps/

Answer (score 122):

This is the simplest solution that worked for me.

```html
<div
  contentEditable='true'
  onInput={e => console.log('Text inside div', e.currentTarget.textContent)}
>
Text inside div
</div>
```

Comment: It move caret to beginning of text constantly when I update text with React state.

Comment: This solution will strip out all the markup and give you just the text content defeating the reason why the content editable div is used. Rather  use innerHTML i.e                            `onInput={(e) =>console.log("Text inside div", e.currentTarget.innerHTML) }`

Comment: This works but as @JuntaeKim suggested, the caret always stays at the beginning and does not change it's position. Any ideas on how to change position of caret?

Comment: @Umang Is react updating the state within the div? If you modify state from the div and then the div is updated based on that state, it replaced the DOM element (I believe) which removes the caret. You'll need to find a way to avoid having react insert state into the div. I just made my own functions to manage state outside of react

Comment: This works great if you need an uncontrolled component. It doesn't work well for controlled situations, as others have mentioned, but React also discourages this with a warning: `A component is \`contentEditable\` and contains \`children\` managed by React. It is now your responsibility to guarantee that none of those nodes are unexpectedly modified or duplicated. This is probably not intentional.`

Comment: I would leave the component uncontrolled and use `onBlur`/`onInput` rather than attempting to control the value and cursor position with React.

Answer (score 85):

Someone has made a project on NPM with my solution: *[react-contenteditable](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable)*

I've encountered another problem that occurs when the browser tries to "reformat" the HTML you just gave it, leading to component always rerendering. [See this](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable/issues/18).

Here's my production contentEditable implementation. It has some additional options over `react-contenteditable` that you might want, including:

- locking
- imperative API allowing to embed HTML fragments
- ability to reformat the content

#### Summary:

FakeRainBrigand's solution has worked quite fine for me for some time until I got new problems. ContentEditables are a pain, and are not really easy to deal with React...

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/8349/) demonstrates the problem.

As you can see, when you type some characters and click on <kbd>Clear</kbd>, the content is not cleared. This is because we try to reset the contenteditable to the last known virtual [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) value.

So it seems that:

- You need `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent caret position jumps
- You can't rely on React's VDOM diffing algorithm if you use `shouldComponentUpdate` this way.

So you need an extra line, so that whenever `shouldComponentUpdate` returns 'yes', you are sure the DOM content is actually updated.

So the version here adds a `componentDidUpdate` and becomes:

```
var ContentEditable = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div id="contenteditable"
            onInput={this.emitChange}
            onBlur={this.emitChange}
            contentEditable
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.html}}></div>;
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps){
        return nextProps.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function() {
        if (this.props.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML) {
           this.getDOMNode().innerHTML = this.props.html;
        }
    },

    emitChange: function() {
        var html = this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
        if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {
            this.props.onChange({
                target: {
                    value: html
                }
            });
        }
        this.lastHtml = html;
    }
});
```

The *virtual* DOM stays outdated, and it may not be the most efficient code, but at least it does work :) [My bug is resolved](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/8352/)

---

**Details:**

1. If you put shouldComponentUpdate to avoid caret jumps, then the contenteditable never rerenders (at least on keystrokes)
2. If the component never rerenders on key stroke, then React keeps an outdated virtual DOM for this contenteditable.
3. If React keeps an outdated version of the contenteditable in its virtual DOM tree, then if you try to reset the contenteditable to the value outdated in the virtual DOM, then during the virtual DOM diff, React will compute that there are no changes to apply to the DOM!

This happens mostly when:

- you have an empty contenteditable initially (shouldComponentUpdate=true,prop="",previous vdom=N/A),
- the user types some text and you prevent renderings (shouldComponentUpdate=false,prop=text,previous vdom="")
- after user clicks a validation button, you want to empty that field (shouldComponentUpdate=false,prop="",previous vdom="")
- as both the newly produced and old virtual DOM are "", React does not touch the DOM.

Comment: I've implemented keyPress version that alert the text when enter key is pressed. http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/11378/

Comment: @LucaColonnello you'd better use `{...this.props}` so that the client can customize this behavior from the outside

Comment: Oh yeah, this is better! Honestly I have tried this solution only to check if the keyPress event working on div! Thanks for clarifications

Comment: Could you explain how the `shouldComponentUpdate` code prevents caret jumps?

Comment: @kmoe because the component never updates if the contentEditable already has the appropriate text (ie on keystroke). Updating the contentEditable with React makes the caret jump. Try without contentEditable and see yourself ;)

Comment: @SebastienLorber Alternative fix to your problem is to shove the HTML from props into a detached container, and then read the innerHTML out, before you do any comparison. See https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable/pull/26/files

Comment: You'll likely want to set `this.lastHtml` somewhere in a constructor if you're going for this approach, otherwise it will fire a change event whenever you trigger blur even though you haven't changed anything yet.

Comment: Instead of preventing caret jumps using `shouldComponentUpdate`, I'm leaning toward manually re-setting the caret in `componentDidUpdate`. I found the awesome selection DOM API to help with that. The entire element gets re-rendered, but the caret stays where it is (technically "goes back" to where it was). I am still having trouble with some weird input range bug.

Comment: Cool implementation. Your JSFiddle link seems to have an issue.

Answer (score 40):

Since, when the edit is complete the focus from the element is always lost, you could simply use an `onBlur` event handler.

```html
<div
  onBlur={e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
  }}
  contentEditable
  suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This answers just a single scenario. There is *still* a need to act upon content change (for example, update custom scrollbars while typing)

Comment: is this supported on all browser ?

Comment: smart and simple!

Answer (score 21):

This probably isn't exactly the answer you're looking for, but having struggled with this myself and having issues with suggested answers, I decided to make it uncontrolled instead.

When `editable` prop is `false`, I use `text` prop as is, but when it is `true`, I switch to editing mode in which `text` has no effect (but at least browser doesn't freak out). During this time `onChange` are fired by the control. Finally, when I change `editable` back to `false`, it fills HTML with whatever was passed in `text`:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
'use strict';

var React = require('react'),
    escapeTextForBrowser = require('react/lib/escapeTextForBrowser'),
    { PropTypes } = React;

var UncontrolledContentEditable = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    component: PropTypes.func,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    editable: PropTypes.bool
  },

  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      component: React.DOM.div,
      editable: false
    };
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      initialText: this.props.text
    };
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.editable && !this.props.editable) {
      this.setState({
        initialText: nextProps.text
      });
    }
  },

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.editable && this.props.editable) {
      this.getDOMNode().innerHTML = escapeTextForBrowser(this.state.initialText);
    }
  },

  render() {
    var html = escapeTextForBrowser(this.props.editable ?
      this.state.initialText :
      this.props.text
    );

    return (
      <this.props.component onInput={this.handleChange}
                            onBlur={this.handleChange}
                            contentEditable={this.props.editable}
                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />
    );
  },

  handleChange(e) {
    if (!e.target.textContent.trim().length) {
      e.target.innerHTML = '';
    }

    this.props.onChange(e);
  }
});

module.exports = UncontrolledContentEditable;
```

Comment: Could you expand on the issues you were having with the other answers?

Comment: @NVI: I need safety from injection, so putting HTML as is is not an option. If I don't put HTML and use textContent, I get all sorts of browser inconsistencies and can't implement `shouldComponentUpdate` so easily so even it doesn't save me from caret jumps anymore. Finally, I have CSS pseudo-element `:empty:before` placeholders but this `shouldComponentUpdate` implementation prevented FF and Safari from cleaning up the field when it is cleared by user. Took me 5 hours to realize I can sidestep all these problems with uncontrolled CE.

Comment: I don’t quite understand how it works. You never change `editable` in `UncontrolledContentEditable`. Could you provide a runnable example?

Comment: @NVI: It's a bit hard since I use a React internal module here.. Basically I set `editable` from outside. Think a field that can be edited inline when user presses “Edit” and should be again readonly when user presses “Save” or “Cancel”. So when it is readonly, I use props, but I stop looking at them whenever I enter “edit mode” and only look at props again when I exit it.

Comment: So this will only work if parent component can provide `text`, `editable` and `onChange`. It does *not* support changing `text` from outside while `editable` is `true`—but you rarely need this anyway.

Comment: For whom you are going to use this code, React has renamed `escapeTextForBrowser` to `escapeTextContentForBrowser`.

Comment: I find this answer to be the most succinct and helpful. Some folks might also want to check out Facebook's [draft-js](https://draftjs.org/) component which does all this and _way_ more.

Comment: I was having little luck getting the approaches in the higher-voted answers to work with `tribute.js`, and I took your component, converted it to ES6, fixed a bug or two, and things seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to do this. It gives you a lot more control over what is going on. It also gives you more details on how the browse interprets all the keystrokes.

Here in TypeScript:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Editor extends React.Component {
    private _root: HTMLDivElement; // Ref to the editable div
    private _mutationObserver: MutationObserver; // Modifications observer
    private _innerTextBuffer: string; // Stores the last printed value

    public componentDidMount() {
        this._root.contentEditable = "true";
        this._mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(this.onContentChange);
        this._mutationObserver.observe(this._root, {
            childList: true, // To check for new lines
            subtree: true, // To check for nested elements
            characterData: true // To check for text modifications
        });
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.onRootRef}>
                Modify the text here ...
            </div>
        );
    }

    private onContentChange: MutationCallback = (mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
        mutations.forEach(() => {
            // Get the text from the editable div
            // (Use innerHTML to get the HTML)
            const {innerText} = this._root;

            // Content changed will be triggered several times for one key stroke
            if (!this._innerTextBuffer || this._innerTextBuffer !== innerText) {
                console.log(innerText); // Call this.setState or this.props.onChange here
                this._innerTextBuffer = innerText;
            }
        });
    }

    private onRootRef = (elt: HTMLDivElement) => {
        this._root = elt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a component that incorporates much of this by lovasoa: https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable/blob/master/src/react-contenteditable.tsx#L97

He shims the event in the emitChange

```
emitChange: function(evt){
    var html = this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
    if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {
        evt.target = { value: html };
        this.props.onChange(evt);
    }
    this.lastHtml = html;
}
```

I'm using a similar approach successfully

Comment: The author has credited my SO answer in package.json. This is almost the same code that I posted and I confirm this code works for me. https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable/blob/master/package.json

Comment: The link is broken (*"404. Page not found"*).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I updated the link based on what I could find in the repo. The code has changed slightly but it looks like the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div
    spellCheck="false"
    onInput={e => console.log("e: ", e.currentTarget.textContent}
    contentEditable="true"
    suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
    placeholder="Title"
    className="new-post-title"
/>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What was it tested on (browser, operating system), incl. versions (incl. React). From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72195285/edit), not here in comments (****************************** ***without*** *********************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: A "`)`" seems to be missing near `"console.log("e: ", e.currentTarget.textContent"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my [hooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#React_hooks)-based version based on [Sebastien Lorber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27255103):

```
const noop = () => {};
const ContentEditable = ({
  html,
  onChange = noop,
}: {
  html: string;
  onChange?: (s: string) => any;
}) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const lastHtml = useRef<string>('');

  const emitChange = () => {
    const curHtml = ref.current?.innerHTML || '';
    if (curHtml !== lastHtml.current) {
      onChange(curHtml);
    }
    lastHtml.current = html;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) return;
    if (ref.current.innerHTML === html) return;
    ref.current.innerHTML = html;
  }, [html]);

  return (
    <div
      onInput={emitChange}
      contentEditable
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}
      ref={ref}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

Comment: i see a perfect vector for XSS here guys, i suppose this is not meant as a serious answer suitable for production. at least you could have mentioned the need for some sanitisation that might or might _not_ happen in the parent component. the best practice is to avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` all together.
see 'React’s dangerouslySetInnerHTML without sanitising the HTML' [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm done with `onInput`. Thank You

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<style>
 div{
  border: .2px solid black;
 }
</style>
# editable
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const { React, ReactDOM} = window;

const App =()=>(
    <div 
       contentEditable={true}
       onInput={(e) => {
         console.log(e.target.innerText);
        }}
     >Edit me</div>
)
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`contentEditable` will make the content inside div editable.

Instead of using `onInput` you can use `onBlur` so that the blinking **cursor will not move to beginning** of text constantly.

Whatever change you make to the text will be visible on the screen and the state will be updated once you move the focus out of the element.

```
<div onBlur={this.onChange} contentEditable>
  {this.state.value}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to use the [example from Saint Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57365612/6243352):

```html
<div
  onBlur={e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
  }}
  contentEditable
  suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

It's working perfectly until I've tried to set this value in state. When I'm using a functional component that calls `setState(e.currentTarget.textContent)`, I'm getting `currentTarget` as null. `setState` works asynchronously and `currentTarget` is not available there.

The fix that worked for me in React 17.0.2 was to use `e.target.innerText`:

```html
<div
  onBlur={e => setState(e.target.innerText)}
  contentEditable
  suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How about using the original approach but storing `e.currentTarget.textContent` in a string variable, e.g. `const {textContent} = e.currentTarget`, then use that variable to set state? This won't go stale as the object property might.