# React.JS - Manage content of contenteditable div as React components

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable

I'm looking for methods of managing elements of `contenteditable` as React components.

Exploring Facebook's source via React DevTools extension reveals that they wrote a `contenteditable` comment editor that seems to be fully managed by React.

[image]

You can see in the components tree that updating the `conteneditable` triggers updates to components tree that are children of `contenteditable`.

Comment: It's not clear what your programming question is. It's too broad to ask for someone to detail out how to create a complex editor.

Comment: Those who are familiar with React, should know about the difficulties concerning with managing a reliable state of contentediatble element while providing a smooth user experience. I'm not asking how to create complex editor, there are plenty of those; I'm rather asking about ways to manage state of contenteditable element as React components.

Comment: Facebook has most likely poured countless of hours into making that control work as smooth as it does. You could probably re-implement it, but count on lots of work. Contenteditable elements are notoriously ridden with tricky edge-cases and browser compatibility issues. Their component is most likely not open and couldn't be - it's probably too deeply integrated with the rest of their system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook just released Draft.js - https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/

Answer (score 2):

**update:**

Facebook has released draft-js which is meant for building text editors with react. 
https://github.com/facebook/draft-js

**original answer which is now outdated:**

Go ahead, there is nothing special for this.

here are some examples:

- https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable
- https://github.com/liamzebedee/reactjs-contenteditable/blob/master/ContentEditable.jsx
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22678516/1536309

Comment: The top link gives a 404. It should be https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable

Answer (score -1):

One use case of controlling content editable in react js:

[image: One use case of controlling content editable in react js]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code would best be provided in text form (as a code block in your answer) instead of an image, which is not accessible for every reader.

Comment: Welcome to SO! All code & error messages must be posted in text format that can be easily copy-pasted into editors & search engines. Pictures of text can be difficult to read, especially on mobile, and said posts may be subject to deletion. Additionally, SO highly encourages explainations how/why your solution solves the OP's issue. Bonus: over time, high quality answers tend to gain more upvotes over time, as future visitors apply knowledge & insight from your post to their owning coding issues. Consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74281493/edit) to improve quality of your post.