# Using a span as text input in React with content-editable

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable

I want to use a span as a simple text input. If I weren't using React, I'd just do this the normal way with content-editable. However, this doesn't work nicely with React.

I know that [Draft.js](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/) and the NPM package [react-contenteditable](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable) both handle some of these complexities for React. But those sort of seem like overkill for this, because I don't want the input to be able to handle anything except plain text.

Should I just use Draft.js or react-contenteditable, or can I do something simpler?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677931/react-js-onchange-event-for-contenteditable

Answer (score 2):

Upon further consideration, [react-contenteditable](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable) seems to be the best solution for this. It's actually pretty lightweight and quite customizable. Also, the source code is short enough and simple enough that I was able to just read the whole thing.

Comment: Just an FYI, this component does not sanitize input. So if you don't know what you are doing it is very easy to introduce XSS vulnerabilities