# Caret position reverts to start of contenteditable span on re-render in React in Safari and Firefox

Tags: firefox, reactjs, safari, contenteditable, caret

When typing text into a contenteditable span in Safari or Firefox the caret moves to the start on each keypress. This only seems to happen when React re/renders the component.

Chrome works just fine. Haven't tested IE.

---

An example where `|` is the caret and typing `Hello`:

`|` `|H` `|eH` `|leH` `|lleH` `|olleH`

Here's a simplified version of my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ContentEditable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: props.value
        };
    }

    createMarkup() {
        return { __html: this.state.value };
    }

    handleInput(event) {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.innerText
        });
    }

    isValid() {
        let bestLength = 3;

        return this.state.value.length > bestLength;
    }

    render() {
        let className = '';
        if (this.isValid()) {
            className = 'is-valid';
        }

        return (
            <span
                contentEditable="true"
                onInput={ this.handleInput.bind(this) }
                className={ className }
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.createMarkup() }
            >
            </span>
        );
    }
}

ContentEditable.propTypes = {
    value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default ContentEditable;
```

Anyone come across this before?

Comment: edit: happens in Safari & Firefox, not in Chrome.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Just tried your example in Firefox and I get the issue. Caret moves to the start of the field when I type in there. I'm on OSX. Firefox 48.0.2 and Safari 10.0.1
[edit: ah, ok. thanks for creating the demo though! http://jsbin.com/gerifud/edit?js,output ]

Comment: Check out some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22677931/6941627

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: any solutions ? pls share , i have got similar issue

Comment: Works with event.target.textContent

Comment: for me @Ranjith Kumar answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881397/react-how-to-maintain-caret-position-when-editing-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve a `contenteditable` by adding a handler to an HTML tag.
The problem is every time content is re-rendered the position of the cursor is reset. You are triggering a `setState` when the content of the `span` is edited, which is resetting the cursor position.

You could rather store a reference to the `span` tag and update its value rather than triggering a state change.

A `ref` could be stored which will inject the value in the span.

```
class ContentEditable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.spanRef = React.createRef();
    this.val = props.value;
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    const { innerText } = event.target;
    if (this.val !== innerText) {
      this.spanRef.innerText = innerText;
      this.val = innerText;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span
        contentEditable="true"
        className={"is-valid"}
        onInput={this.handleInput.bind(this)}
        ref={this.spanRef}
        suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
      >
        {this.val}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

[Running code](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-snowflake-19o99?file=/src/input.js:79-683)

Comment: not working position jumps to starting position

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but this will might help someone else, or you can also find similar type of solution on other questions too.

Html works of Node concept when you update or print value in node directly because of react re-rending it reset the cursor position to start. you have to pass value programatically to element using the HTML web API's here is the modified code.

```
class ContentEditable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.spanRef = React.createRef();
    this.val = props.value;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevPorps){
    if(prevPorps?.value !== this.props.value) {
       this.spanRef.innerText = this.props.value;
    }
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    const { innerText } = event.target;
    if (this.val !== innerText) {
      this.spanRef.innerText = innerText;
      this.val = innerText;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span
        contentEditable="true"
        className={"is-valid"}
        onInput={this.handleInput.bind(this)}
        ref={this.spanRef}
        suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
      >
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```