# React: How to maintain caret position when editing contentEditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**Currently**

1. I have a react component that stores a `newValue` when the user clicks on a contentEditable `<div>`, and updates `newValue` as the user types. *Note: there are 2 main reasons why I have set up this behavior this way: (1) I do not want to send the data to be saved on every key stroke, and (2) I plan to use a variation of this div where each input is checked to verify whether the input is a number.*
2. The `newValue` is sent to be saved when the `<div>` loses focus, and then the state of the prop is reset.

**Problem**

The `onChangeHandler` is moving the position of the caret within the editable div to the left hand side. This results in the key strokes `123456` appearing as `654321`

Code:

```
class Input extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //newValue input by user
      newValue : undefined
    }
  }

  //handler during key press / input
  onChangeHandler = event => {
    let targetValue =  event.currentTarget.textContent;
    this.setState({"newValue": targetValue})
  }

  //handler when user opens input form
  onBlurHandler = event => {
    //some code that sends the "newValue" to be saved, and resets state
  }

  render() {
    //determine which value to show in the div
    let showValue;
    //if there is a new value being input by user, show this value
    if (this.state.newValue !== undefined) {
      showValue = this.state.newValue;
    } else {
      //if prop has no value e.g. null or undefined, use "" placeholder
      if (this.props.value) {
        showValue = this.props.value;
      } else {
        showValue = "";
      }
    }

    return (
    <table>
    <tbody>
      <td>
          <div
            contentEditable="true"
            suppressContentEditableWarning="true"
            onInput={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)}
            onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
          >{showValue}
          </div>
      </td>
     </tbody>
     </table>
    )
  }
}

export default Input;
```

**Notes**

1. I previously was doing this with a `<textarea>` which did not have this issue, but switched to `<div>` for more control over the auto-adjusting div height behavior (ref [CSS: Remove scroll bar and replace with variable height for textarea in a table <td>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811423/css-remove-scroll-bar-and-replace-with-variable-height-for-textarea-in-a-table))
2. I have been able to find numerous related answers, but none that are specific to react e.g. [Maintain cursor position in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194364/maintain-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div). I assume because react is reloading the component after each stroke, this issue is occurring.
3. I previously had no ChangeHandler onInput, and this was working fine, but I was unable to log each key press and validate whether the character was a number.

Comment: Make a FiddleJS of your component and I'll help you debug

Comment: I actually tried to make a Fiddlejs at first, but failed to get it working. This is as far as I got: https://jsfiddle.net/e4utgwc1/. I am not sure how to handle the react and react-dom modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get this working following solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/1730260

Key changes:

1. Add new component `EditCaretPositioning.js` with 2 functions: (1) saveSelection to save caret position, and (2) restoreSelection to restore caret position.
2. Save the caret position in the state of `Input` component
3. Call `saveSelection()` after every *Change* event
4. `restoreSelection()` as a callback after setting the state
5. Added `id` to `<div>` so can reference in `restoreSelection()` function

**EditCaretPositioning.js**

```
const EditCaretPositioning = {}

export default EditCaretPositioning;


if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    //saves caret position(s)
    EditCaretPositioning.saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
        preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
        preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + range.toString().length
        }
    };
    //restores caret position(s)
    EditCaretPositioning.restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
        var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

        while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                    foundStart = true;
                }
                if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                    stop = true;
                }
                charIndex = nextCharIndex;
            } else {
                var i = node.childNodes.length;
                while (i--) {
                    nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }



} else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
  //saves caret position(s)
    EditCaretPositioning.saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var selectedTextRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var preSelectionTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        preSelectionTextRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        preSelectionTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selectedTextRange);
        var start = preSelectionTextRange.text.length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + selectedTextRange.text.length
        }
    };
    //restores caret position(s)
    EditCaretPositioning.restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", savedSel.end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", savedSel.start);
        textRange.select();
    };

}
```

**Updated contentEditable div component:**

```
import CaretPositioning from 'EditCaretPositioning'

class Input extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //newValue input by user
      newValue : undefined,
      //stores positions(s) of caret to handle reload after onChange end
      caretPosition : {
        start : 0,
        end : 0
      }
    }
  }

  //handler during key press / input
  onChangeHandler = event => {
    let targetValue =  event.currentTarget.textContent;
    //save caret position(s), so can restore when component reloads
    let savedCaretPosition = CaretPositioning.saveSelection(event.currentTarget);
    this.setState({
      "newValue": targetValue,
      "caretPosition" : savedCaretPosition
    }, () => {
      //restore caret position(s)
      CaretPositioning.restoreSelection(document.getElementById("editable"), this.state.caretPosition);
    })
  }

  //handler when user opens input form
  onBlurHandler = event => {
    //some code that sends the "newValue" to be saved, and resets state
  }

  render() {
    //determine which value to show in the div
    let showValue;
    //if there is a new value being input by user, show this value
    if (this.state.newValue !== undefined) {
      showValue = this.state.newValue;
    } else {
      //if prop has no value e.g. null or undefined, use "" placeholder
      if (this.props.value) {
        showValue = this.props.value;
      } else {
        showValue = "";
      }
    }

    return (
    <table>
    <tbody>
      <td>
          <div
            id="editable"
            contentEditable="true"
            suppressContentEditableWarning="true"
            onInput={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)}
            onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
          >{showValue}
          </div>
      </td>
     </tbody>
     </table>
    )
  }
}

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 3):

ContentEditable is a tricky especially with react as you have to account for a lot of different kind of behaviors. May I suggest you take a look at DraftJS by Facebook.

They took contentEditable and prevented all default behavior and built a nice framework to make a tag editable, they use it for a rich text editor but you can use the same framework without all the bells and whistle to just take control of the content editable.

https://draftjs.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. It's the nuclear option to solve my problem, so I would like to avoid for now, especially since I want to try and use this contentEditable div for number input with validation and no styles, I'd need to either hack DraftJS, build a Div solution, or build a non-Div solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I too have faced this issue, while trying content editable on a `<td>`. The cursor goes to the start while editing, I tried multiple methods but nothing helps!

Later, I ended up using this "contenteditable" React package.

https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable

Previously, My code used was like this

```
   <td 
      onInput={(e) =>this.handleInput(e, user, "name", index)}
      contentEditable={user.isEditable}
      className={
        user.isEditable ? "border  border-success" : ""
      }
   >
     {user.name}
   </td>
```

After including the package, I changed that with the below code. And now it works without any issues.

```
<td className={user.isEditable ? "border border-success" : ""}>
   <ContentEditable
      html={user.name}
      disabled={!user.isEditable}
      onChange={(e) =>
      this.handleInput(e, user, "name", index)
      }
      style={{ "text-decoration": "none" }}
   />
 </td>
```