# How to pass contenteditable attribute to html?

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable, react-rails

I want to make content editable by using `contenteditable` attribute. But when I add it to my component - it's nowhere to be found.

```
class CompName extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="CompName" >
        <div contenteditable={true}>Somecontent</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Tried using `true` as string as well. Am I missing something fundamental here? I'm fairly new to React..

I am using `react-rails` gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [reactjs docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-children-with-jsx):

> Since JSX is closer to JavaScript than HTML, React DOM uses `camelCase`
>   property naming convention instead of HTML attribute names. For
>   example, `class` becomes **`className`** in JSX, and `tabindex` becomes
>   **`tabIndex`**.

You have to use `contentEditable={true}`:

```
class CompName extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="comp-name" >
        <div contentEditable={true}>Somecontent</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Haven't tried `contenteditable` html elements with react yet but i could imagine depending on how you want to use them you will encounter some issues without any further updating logic in your component.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it as contentEditable not contenteditable.
This is not html, it's JSX. You should follow the JS convention while passing attributes.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677931/react-js-onchange-event-for-contenteditable

Comment: It worked! .. so react knows all the possible html attributes? And accordingly it only allows those?

Comment: @Aurimas Yes. [Read here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes) for a list of supported attributes.