# How to implement react with on type (realtime) emojis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji, emojione

I have a chat app written on react.

I need the following:

- When the user write a smile name, e.g. `:smile:` should converted into *emojione*, **not unicode**.
- The input must be as the code below.
- The emojis in the input should look the same as they look in the conversation.

```html
<div contentEditable
     styles={this.state.messageInputStyle}
     className="message-input">
</div>
```

Comment: What have you researched and tried?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I tried **react-emojione**, `onKeyUp` I check the `innerHTML` of the input if it has `Text` node and contains e.g. `:smile:`, then I apply `emojify` then insert it. It is really ugly and I believe that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27255103) is a nice way to make a `contentEditable` div with `html` and `onChange` props. i used that with `emojione`'s `shortnameToImage` function.

[here is a working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQMKYE)

the styles can be added to `ContentEditable` props if you want them to come from the state

the only thing that needs to be fixed is the caret position after an emoji is added.

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "Start Writing Here"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ContentEditable
        html={emojione.shortnameToImage(this.state.value)}
        onChange={this._onChange}
      />
    );
  }

  _onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };
}

var ContentEditable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div
        contentEditable
        className="message-input"
        onInput={this.emitChange}
        onBlur={this.emitChange}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.html }}
      />
    );
  },

  shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps) {
    return nextProps.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    if (this.props.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML) {
      this.getDOMNode().innerHTML = this.props.html;
    }
  },

  emitChange: function() {
    var html = this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;

    if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {
      this.props.onChange({ target: { value: html } });
    }

    this.lastHtml = html;
  }
});

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%
}

.message-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.emojione {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used [emojione](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emojione) and [this code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/4tUDk/) to basically come up with a very non-react solution as shown below. Hope it helps.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import emojione from 'emojione';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    updateText = () => {
        const html = emojione.shortnameToImage(this.refs.inputDiv.innerHTML);
        let sel, range;

        if (window.getSelection) {
            // IE9 and non-IE
            sel = window.getSelection();

            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();

                // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
                // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
                let el = this.refs.inputDiv;
                el.innerHTML = html;
                let frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;

                while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                    lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
                }
                range.insertNode(frag);

                // Preserve the selection
                if (lastNode) {
                    range = range.cloneRange();
                    range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                    range.collapse(true);
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                }
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
            // IE < 9
            document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
        }
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="inputDiv" contentEditable onInput={this.updateText}/>
        );
    }

}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/ol2lmkqqlq