# props onChange is not triggering

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to enter a value whenever a user enters a value when edit is selected, it **will not let me enter a value**.

I suspect it should be something to do with the `onChange` method, I'm not sure what I should do. I think the `onChange` method is right.

I read a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408603/react-onchange-not-triggering-from-div), but doesn't have the solution I'm looking for.

**PostList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            isEditing:false,
            isEditingId:null
        }
    }
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }
    // this will be onChange used for the <Editable component/>
    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.title]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {
        this.setState({
            isEditingId: id
          });
    }

    render(){
        const {posts, editForm, isEditing, editChange} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                    <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                    {/* {...post} prevents us from writing all of the properties out */}
                        <PostItem editChange={this.onChange} editForm={this.formEditing} isEditing={this.state.isEditingId === post.id} removePost={this.removePost} {...post} />
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**Editable.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const Editable = (props) => (
    <div>
        <TextField
            id="outlined-name"
            label="Title"
            style={{width: 560}}
            name="title"
            value={props.editField}
            onChange={props.editChange}
            margin="normal"
            variant="outlined"/>

    </div>
)

export default Editable;
```

**PostItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import Editable from './Editable';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
// editChange will passed in as an argument. So the <Editable/> component can 
//use it
const PostItem = ({ title, id,  removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange}) => {
    return(
         <div>
                <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                {/* if else teneray operator */}
                {isEditing ? (
                    <Editable editField={title} editChange={editChange}/>
                ): (
                    <div>
                        {title}
                    </div>    
                )}         
                </Typography>
                <Typography component="p">
                    {post_content}
                    <h5>
                        by: {username}</h5>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                </Typography>
                {!isEditing ? (
                    <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                        Edit
                    </Button>
                ):(
                    <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(null)}>
                        Update
                    </Button>
                )}
                <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={removePost(id)}>
                    Remove
                </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default PostItem;
```

update()

I want to keep the current title value instead of deleting the value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're not passing down the changed value. You do `setState` with some `title` but don't do anything with it.

Comment: if thats the case what should i do next ?

Comment: Is ``editChange`` being set? What do you get if you console.log it?

Comment: editChange has been set `<Editable editField={title} editChange={editChange}/>` then it is called

Comment: `<PostItem editChange={this.onChange} editForm={this.formEditing} isEditing={this.state.isEditingId === post.id} removePost={this.removePost} {...post} />`

Comment: console.log onChange ??? how would i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not passing down your title state correctly. Add these to your state to initialize to empty:

```
this.state ={
     isEditing:false,
     isEditingId:null,
     title: ""
}
```

onChange to this

```
  onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }
```

**PostItem** to this

```
const PostItem = ({ title, id,  removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange }) => {
    return(
         <div>
                <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                {/* if else teneray operator */}
                {isEditing ? (
                    <Editable editField={title} editChange={editChange}/>
                ): (
                    <div>
                        {title}
                    </div>    
                )}         
                </Typography>
                <Typography component="p">
                    {post_content}
                    <h5>
                        by: {username}</h5>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                </Typography>
                {!isEditing ? (
                    <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                        Edit
                    </Button>
                ):(
                    <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(null)}>
                        Update
                    </Button>
                )}
                <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={removePost(id)}>
                    Remove
                </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default PostItem;
```

Then pass down title to your PostItem as props,

for example

```
 <PostItem title={this.state.title} editChange={this.onChange} editForm={this.formEditing} isEditing={this.state.isEditingId === post.id} removePost={this.removePost} {...post} />
```

**update**

change this

```
<Editable editField={myTitle} editChange={editChange}/>
```

to(this makes it so the title is appended in the values while you can still edit the value feel free to improve this) it acts a little buggy or wierd but it work.

```
 <Editable editField={title} editChange={editChange}/>
```

Comment: How would i pass the title to postItem props, can you demonstrate how i would do that ? thanks :)

Comment: <PostItem title={this.state.title} editChange={this.onChange} editForm={this.formEditing} isEditing={this.state.isEditingId === post.id} removePost={this.removePost} {...post} />

Comment: this don't seem to work, let me see what im doing wrong

Comment: I also think there's a problem with your onChange function. You are using event.target.title but it is not defined. Can you also change into this:

this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: e.target.value
        })

Comment: i got it working, im going to make an edit to you answer.

Comment: Is their a way i can do this `editField={myTitle}`. Like edit the the title that is already set. You know what i mean ?

Comment: as of now, when i click edit it deletes the value that is already set. I'll show an example

Comment: Just wondering if you really need the update button? Since you are using a TextField you could just click on the text field and edit the current Title

Comment: im going to need it later to update the value on back end.

Comment: i just want the {title} to append to the value.

Comment: i think i figured it out. let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Ok got it. Based on reading your code, I think you're displaying the title props but you are editing the myTitle props. I think it should be the same like,

{isEditing ? (
                    <Editable editField={myTitle} editChange={editChange}/>
                ): (
                    <div>
                        {myTitle}
                    </div>    
                )}

Comment: i just updated it check the edit, let me know ur thoughts.

Comment: I just checked your edit, It should work but you will be using two variables. Which I think using one is enough. Why not directly edit title instead of declaring another variable called myTitle? Altho I'm not sure if you need those two variables on other parts of your code.

Comment: can you please show me in code how you would do it, its hard to understand in words.

Comment: Sure. I improved your edit :) With this, you will just be editing the title only and display the updated one

Comment: thanks for the edit, but when changing mytitle to title which title is actually the mapped post attribute. It leads me back to square one, where i can not enter a value in the input field.

Comment: I see. Well I guess appending should be fine

Comment: nevermind its too much work putting it up on sandbox. Ill just leave it like it is. Thank you for your time and effort.