# How can i change my non input tag in react?

Tags: reactjs

const [text, setText] = useState('Hello  friend')

return

```
<p>{text}</p>
```

How can I put a cursor between a hello and a friend and write something? It should look like I write in a p or div tag, not like I write in a text area or input.

Comment: We might need more details for your question. Can you give more context?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677931/react-js-onchange-event-for-contenteditable/27255103#27255103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `contentEditable` attribute, and `useRef`:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const text = useRef("Hello friend");

  const handleChange = e => {
    text.current = e.target.innerText
  };

  return (
    <p contentEditable="true" onInput={handleChange}>
      {text.current}
    </p>
  );
}
```

Making this work with `useState` might be difficult. Could you use an `<input>` and style it to look like a `<p>`?

```
input {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```