# ReactJs: Listen to event in "span" tag ES6

Tags: reactjs

I have a class-based component, having the below codes within it:

```
state = {value: "Hello", input: null}

inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
} 

changeValueHandler = () => {
    this.setState({value: this.state.input})
}

render(){
    <div>
        <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.inputChangeHandler} />
        <button onClick={(event) => this.inputChangeHandler(event)}>Save input</button>
    </div>
}
```

This works: When I type "World" in the input box then press save. The title changes from "Hello" to "World".

However, I want to have an expandable input box to support longer input paragraphs. So I replace the `<input>` tag with `<span>`:

```
<span type="text" role="textbox" onChange={this.inputChangeHandler} contentEditable={true} />
```

This doesn't work: **When I type "World" in the span box then press save. The title is still the default "Hello", even though I intend to change it to "World".**

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js: onChange event for contentEditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677931/react-js-onchange-event-for-contenteditable)

Comment: Hope this helps, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-forked-13hmd

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Thank you! You solved my issue

Comment: @YigeSong, Glad to help you..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I have this problem in my actual code after implementing your solution: every time after typing a character in the span box, the cursor moves to the beginning of the span box. In my actual code the inputChangeHandler is like ```inputChangeHandler(event, param)```, and I use it by ```onInput={(event) => this.ainputChangeHandler(event, param)```. Do you know what's wrong? I tried to search online but got no helpful result. Thanks again

Comment: @YigeSong ..  In question you have function name as ```this.inputChangeHandler``` but you have included ```a``` in start of name like ```this.ainputChangeHandler``` .. Is this just typo or you have mismatching of names in your real app?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan sorry this is a typo. In the real program, there's no typo. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @YigeSong, Can you please replicate the issue in the codesandbox for better understanding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223284/discussion-between-yige-song-and-maniraj-murugan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change,

```
<span type="text" role="textbox" onChange={this.inputChangeHandler} contentEditable={true} />
```

**To:**

```
<span contentEditable="true" onInput={this.inputChangeHandler}>
  Some text{" "}
</span>
```

So in contentEditable you have to use `onInput` to capture the change event.

Then modify `inputChangeHandler` like,

```
  inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ input: event.currentTarget.textContent });
  };
```

Here we need to take `event.currentTarget.textContent` that has the change in text user type.

[image: Edit React basic class component (forked)]