# Debounce with two directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app makes use of socketio to push changes in a textarea to all connected clients. When a user types in the textarea I want two things to happen:

1) Push the text via the socket immediately

2) Save the text to the DB after each change with a 1 second debounce

I've tried this but it won't push or save for some reason:

```
<div ng-model="text" ng-keyup="push()" ng-change="save()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"></div>
```

I've also tried this from the docs:

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change', debounce: {'change': 1000} }"
```

but still no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `<textarea>` instead of `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

`div` doesn't throw an `onchange` event. You should be using an `<input>` element. Otherwise, you'll have to identify when the contents change and manually call `save()`.

See: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6676218/413397 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange