# How can I detect when the contents of a div are unloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, browser

I have an application that navigates mostly with AJAX, and a section where a user can view information. I would like to track how long users are viewing different pieces of information. I want to assume that as long as they have the information loaded in the `<div>` they are "viewing" it. However when the user click on a link to "go to another section of the app" the `<div>` gets loaded with different content, the page doesn't actually redirect.

Does anyone have a solution for this, or at least some thoughts to help me see something I cannot see right now?

Thanks

Comment: monitor for hashchange event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call some function when you update your content.

Since there is no "onchange" event for divs, you'll have to call your function after the ajax process: [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676186/use-onchange-in-a-div).

However, if your content doesn't change according to ajax calls, you should trigger some event when your div changes.

Hope I helped you: without any code fragment I can't do more!

Answer (score 1):

Most analytics software will allow you track this. I have some experience with Google Analytics and it's something like:

```
ga.track("my-event", my_data);
```

Setting up a timer shouldn't be too hard. Put that code in the routine that handles content un/loading.

Comment: can you please explain the - the routine that handles content un/loading? do I need google analytics to do this? Or can I handle the events myself?

Comment: I assume you have this routine already .. how else is content getting loading/unloaded when clicking a link? Also, what analytics software are you using?

Comment: I have Google Analytics, and I do have routing functionality setup - now that you say that I understand what you mean. I will test and report.