# How can detect content changes in DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know form elements can use `onchange` function. But for DIV elements, how can we detect and use in another function? I need to change some HTML displays according to the changes in a particular DIV tag.
eg:

Div "txt1" changes by some form elements in the page change. My requirement is .. Whenever a change occur in div txt1, div txt2 become visible (`style="visibility:visible;"`)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: are these contenteditable div with a user editing ? or just any random change in the div. It will be a duplicate either case, but still just curious.

Comment: its a random change

Comment: What kind of event? @user1010966

Comment: With Ajax. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676186/use-onchange-in-a-div

Comment: I have edited my question for better understanding