# How to detect change of text in a tag done by javascript

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have a code in which i am changes a tag's inner text with js but i want that tag to call a function when it is changes, i dont know why i doesn't call to the function when it is changes please help.Sorry for my bad english.
This is an example of what i am trying to achieve :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="result"></h1>

<p id="demo" onchange="myFunction()">Click button to change my HTML content</p>

<button id="press" onclick="changeText()">button</button>

<script>
function changeText() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "hhhhhhhhhh";
}
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = "Text changed!";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you know everywhere that will change the content, you could just call `myFunction()` from inside `changeText()` If this is just an example and you actually don't control the function making the changes, it would be worth mentioning that in the question.

Comment: The `change` event is only available on form (`<input/>`, `<select>`, ...) elements and not on paragraphs (`<p>`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676186/use-onchange-in-a-div